# Error when updating billing details for admins and contributers

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, payment-processor, 4.6.2, paypal

Version 4.6.2
Platform: Wordpress
Payment Processor: Paypal Payments Pro

So I just noticed that in any membership or recurring contribution email when you go to update the billing address (the token is `{ts 1=$updateSubscriptionBillingUrl}`) you get this error:
`Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl as array in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/Form.php on line 212.`

I then realized that when you go in an an admin and try to do edit billing details you get the same error.

I am not sure if this is new since I upgraded or has been around for a while, but it seems like a pretty large issue. In all my searching I havent found anyone with the same or even near the same issues so I wonder if this is a new bug.

The lines of code at 212 are

```
public static function getPaymentFields($paymentProcessor) {
  $paymentProcessorObject = CRM_Core_Payment::singleton(($paymentProcessor['is_test'] ? 'test' : 'live'), $paymentProcessor);   #this is 212
  return $paymentProcessorObject->getPaymentFormFields();
}
```

Any ideas what the issue is and how I might start to solve it? Ill report anything I come up with here.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the url of the page where you have this error? (you can replace your domain name by example.org, that's the path that I want to know)

Comment: haha yeah thats helpful, its any update to billing so "https://example.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/updatebilling&reset=1&crid=134&cs=a6a404c411b2b31b373aae52707ec3c6_1423450133_inf

Comment: Still getting this error for myself in the admin site and also any contributor or member who tries to update their billing info. Super confused.

Comment: do you get the same behavior on the demo sites?

Comment: Any luck here? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Its fixed on the latest version of civicrm. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/paypal-pro-update-billing-details-for-recurring-payments-link-is-broken-after-up?noredirect=1#comment7009_3797