# Paypal Pro update billing details for recurring payments link is broken after upgrading to 4.6. How to fix it?

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, paypal

Since I have upgraded to 4.6.4, the link to update the billing details from recurring payment receipts is broken. I get the following message from log. How to fix it please?

```
2015/07/08 13:34:52 [error] 23640#0: *14724 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl as array in /srv/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/Form.php on line 220" while reading response header from upstream, client: 185.59.126.253, server: abc.com, request: "GET /index.php?q=civicrm/contribute/updatebilling&reset=1&coid=17747&cs=0bf9ca34f74268e1ff962830b2162a05_1436189654_inf HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/adb.sock:", host: "rldb.info"
```

Comment: I'd upgrade to 4.6.9 first, see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you. It wasn't fixed until 4.6.8. I have upgraded to 4.6.9 and working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have Fixed on Civicrm 4.6.9