# Network Error - Unable To Reach The Server - Change Payment Details on Recurring Contributions

Tags: civicontribute, paypal, recurring-contributions

I am having a problem on CiviCRM 4.6.7 - I get Network Error - Unable to Reach the Server when attempting to "Change Payment Details". Additionally the email sent out, "Recurring Contribution Notification" contains a link,

```
https://www.mydomain.com/index.php?q=civicrm/contribute/unsubscribe&reset=1&crid=35&cs=2cca06426fd09762c341ef901c4c54d0_1440702135_inf
```

And it goes to a blank page

After enabling back-trace/debugging and I right-click and open Change Payment Details in a New Tab, a blank page loads, the error on console says

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Using Paypal Website Payment Pro.

Could this be a permissions issue? Or what?

The links in the email sent out to update / cancel contribution work fine.

Update:

Apache error log entry

```
[Thu Aug 27 15:25:35 2015] [error] [client 67.189.24.160] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalImpl as array in /srv/www/www.mysite.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/Form.php on line 220, referer: https://www.mysite.com/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=4687
```

Code referenced:

```
  /**
   * @param array $paymentProcessor
   * @todo it will be necessary to set details that affect it - mostly likely take Country as a param. Should we add generic
   * setParams on processor class or just setCountry which we know we need?
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public static function getPaymentFields($paymentProcessor) {
    $paymentProcessorObject = CRM_Core_Payment::singleton(($paymentProcessor['is_test'] ? 'test' : 'live'), $paymentProcessor);
    return $paymentProcessorObject->getPaymentFormFields();
  }
```

Update two: this is related issue it looks like: [Error when updating billing details for admins and contributers](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/828/error-when-updating-billing-details-for-admins-and-contributers)

I haven't re-created on demo, because its not set up for recurring contributions AFAIK.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue for updating billing address link for recurring contributions. its been reported here but no answers so far http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3797/paypal-pro-update-billing-details-for-recurring-payments-link-is-broken-after-up  We are not able to reproduce it on demo site as there is no option for web pro payments

Comment: What is the next step? Making an official bug report? This essentially means 'worflow for recurring contributions using Paypal Website Payment Pro' is broken

Comment: Drupal 7.61
CiviCRM 5.4.1

I am having the same issue. I get "Network Error - Unable to Reach the Server" When you click Edit or Change Billing, you get a console Error and a Warning.

Warning =
jquery.min.js?pjxwd7:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Error =
VM1127:1 GET https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/custom?type=ContributionRecur&entityID=435&qf=496c01d04d439a922d8daf4369736266_8787&cgcount=1&snippet=json 403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from a bug introduced in 4.6.x series, fixed in 4.6.9, as per

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17108

Solution: update CiviCRM to the most recent 4.6.x